# Terminal, Nautilus, FF and some other applications have a very narrow scrollbar. How can I expand it?

Tags: 20.04, gui, scrollbar

Terminal, Nautilus, FF and some other applications have a very narrow scrollbar. It is difficult to catch on with the mouse. How can I expand it? I have ubuntu on 20.04.